# Apache - virtualhost - works only one

Tags: apache2, xampp, virtualhost

I need a couple of virtualhosts on my local dev machine.
Unfortunately it needs to be windows.

httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin mateusz.tracz@vd.pl
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin mateusz.tracz@vd.pl
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/manadom.local/public"
   ServerName manadom.local
   ErrorLog "logs/manadom.local-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/manadom.local-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin mateusz.tracz@vd.pl
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/galeriabiznesu"
  ServerName gb.loc
  ErrorLog "logs/gb.loc-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/gb.loc-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 manadom.local
127.0.0.1 gb.loc
```

The problem is: 
localhost points to

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/manadom.local/public
```

manadom.local points to

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/manadom.local/public too
```

gb.loc points to

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/manadom.local/public
```

I can't idea what's wrong?

Please help me, i'm not an admin but i read about it lot and i don't know what possibly i can do wrong.

Comment: Did you restart the Apache after changing configuration files?

Comment: Yes. [some text to make it 12 characters]

Comment: Check if you file is included in httpd.conf - look for a line: 

    Include conf/httpd-vhost.conf

Comment: Dev-machine setup is off-topic for ServerFault, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3):

For named virtual hosts you have to set "NamedVirtualHosts" directive. Please look at the manual -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as said,  before virtual hosts directives you should have:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```